# how to auto play multiple videos tag in one page html with opening modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page that should display two different videos in two different modals.

I want the video to start playing automatically whenever the play-video icon is clicked and the modal is opened.I did this with this code(video.forEach(video => video.play());) but both videos start playing.

And when the modal is open and the video is playing, the video is cut and the modal is closed by the user clicking on the window or modal-closed screen.I did this with this code:( video.forEach(video => video.pause());).

I just have to do this with JavaScript

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
// modal and video
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
var playVideo = document.getElementsByClassName("play-video");
var modalClose = document.getElementsByClassName("modal--close");
var video = document.querySelectorAll('video');
function setDataIndex() {
   for (i = 0; i < playVideo.length; i++){
        playVideo[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        modal[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        modalClose[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        video.forEach(video => video.play());
   }
}
for (i = 0; i < playVideo.length; i++){
     playVideo[i].onclick = function() {
     var ElementIndex = this.getAttribute('data-index');
     modal[ElementIndex].style.display = "block";
    };
    modalClose[i].onclick = function() {
       var ElementIndex = this.getAttribute('data-index');
       modal[ElementIndex].style.display = "none";
       video.forEach(video => video.pause());
    };
}
window.onload = function() {
   setDataIndex();
};
window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target === modal[event.target.getAttribute('data-index')]) {
          modal[event.target.getAttribute('data-index')].style.display = "none";
          video.forEach(video => video.pause());
   }
};
// modal and video
```

```css
:root{
    /* colors */
    --cws: #121214;         /*color name: Woodsmoke               RGB: 18, 18, 20              */
    --clo: #2A827c;         /*color name: Lochinvar               RGB: 42, 130, 124            */
    --cpr: #3CBBB0;         /*color name: Puerto Rico             RGB: 60, 187, 176            */
    --cwa: #7C809B;         /*color name: Waterloo                RGB: 124, 128, 155           */
    --csp: #F5EDF0;         /*color name: Soft Peach              RGB: 245, 237, 240           */
    --cwh: #FFFFFF;         /*color name: White                   RGB: 255, 255, 255           */
}
.play-video{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}

/* modal */
.modal{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:13;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    background: rgba(124, 128, 155,.8); 
}

.modal.active{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal--content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.modal--header{
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
}

.modal--close{
    color: var(--cws);
    font-size: 3rem;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
}
  
.modal--close:hover,
.modal--close:focus {
    color: var(--csp);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal--body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal--body video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 15px solid var(--csp);
}
/* modal */
```

```html
<!--  icon play -->
<div class="play-video"></div>
<div class="play-video"></div>
<!--  icon play -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal">
     <div class="modal--header">
           <span class="modal--close">&times;</span>
     </div>
     <div class="modal--content">
           <div class="modal--body">
                <video controls class="inlineVideo" autoplay="autoplay">
                  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgNkCrAhTGc" >
           </video>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal">
     <div class="modal--header">
           <span class="modal--close">&times;</span>
     </div>
     <div class="modal--content">
           <div class="modal--body">
                <video controls class="inlineVideo" autoplay="autoplay">
                  <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ0cJiVr2-w" >
           </video>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// modal and video
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
var playVideo = document.getElementsByClassName("play-video");
var modalClose = document.getElementsByClassName("modal--close");
var video = document.querySelectorAll('video');
function setDataIndex() {
   for (i = 0; i < playVideo.length; i++){
        playVideo[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        modal[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        modalClose[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
        video[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
   }
}
for (i = 0; i < playVideo.length; i++){
     playVideo[i].onclick = function() {
     var ElementIndex = this.getAttribute('data-index');
     modal[ElementIndex].style.display = "block";
    };
    modalClose[i].onclick = function() {
       var ElementIndex = this.getAttribute('data-index');
       modal[ElementIndex].style.display = "none";
       video.forEach(video => video.pause());
    };
}
window.onload = function() {
   setDataIndex();
};
window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target === modal[event.target.getAttribute('data-index')]) {
          modal[event.target.getAttribute('data-index')].style.display = "none";
          video[ElementIndex].play();
   }
};
// modal and video
```